# Delete a property from JavaScript object without using delete operator

Tags: javascript

I need to extract certain properties from an object and assign to a new object. In a traditional way, I can assign manually whats required from an object property to a new object's property.

Currently i am using delete operator on the original object and creating a new object.

Is there a better way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ES6 Deconstructing Operator you can do a

```
ler arr = [{id:1, name: foo}, {id:2, name: bar}]
arr.map({id, ...item} => {
   return item
})
```

Consider you want to remove id property the above code will remove the id property and returns the object containing the name property.

Answer (score 4):

You could destructure an object and pick the unwanted and get the rest as result object.

It uses

- [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)

  ```
  { [key]:_, ...result } = object;
    ^^^^^
  ```
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with an

  ```
  { [key]:_, ...result } = object;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ```
- [Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) (which is not used anymore) and

  ```
  { [key]:_, ...result } = object;
          ^
  ```
- [Rest in Object Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring)

  ```
  { [key]:_, ...result } = object;
             ^^^
  ```

```js
var object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 },
    key = 'a',
    { [key]:_, ...result } = object;

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Great answer! Could you explain how `[key]:_` works and what the idea behind it is called?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanations, much appreciated!